# How to add attribute to NSManagedObject class?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

I have a core data class that I created from my model file.

Just like this:

[image]

And then I used the editor to generate a sub class of NSManagedObject for that entity like this:

[image]

And this is the class that was generated for me:

[image]

But now I want to add another attribute to my Target entity...obviously I cant just add an attribute to the class, so what is the right way to do so? lets say I want to add an NSString property like:  `@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * someProperty;`

Thanksss

Comment: I'd add it into the model, and generate again the class file.

Comment: a better approach: have classes for the machine and others for u. http://rentzsch.github.io/mogenerator/

Answer (score 1):

1. In that editor drop down, choose `Add Model Version` to create a new version of the model.
2. In the utilities inspector on the right side of Xcode, make sure you set your new version as current model version. It will then have a little green checkmark next to it.
3. Back in the navigator on the left side, select and make sure your new model version is highlighted and add your new attribute to the entity.
4. Now you can either add your property to the class under `body` and `time`, or you can delete that class and regenerate from the model.

Answer (score 0):

You must to create a category:

NSManagedObject+Custom.h

```
#import <CoreData/CoreData.h>

@interface NSManagedObject (Custom)

- (NSString *)someProperty;

@end
```

NSManagedObject+Custom.m

```
#import "NSManagedObject+Custom.h"

@implementation NSManagedObject (Custom)

- (NSString *)someProperty {
    @throw [NSException exceptionWithName:@"someProperty Not Overridden" reason:@"Must override someProperty on NSManagedObject class" userInfo:nil];

    return nil;
}

@end
```

Target.m

```
#import "Target.h"
#import "NSManagedObject+Custom.h"

@implementation Item

@dynamic body;
@dynamic time;

- (NSString)someProperty {
    return @"Some property";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want the property to be persisted then I would add it to the core data entity and delete and regenerate the `.h` and `.m` files.

If the new property doesn't need to be persisted you can add it to the file that was generated like you would do with a normal class. Those properties are not persisted and you can not query them when using `NSPredicate`. A thing to keep in mind is that you might want to change your model in the future and if you regenerate that file, you'd have to somehow make sure to save those additional changes you've made. Having a category that appends the custom changes to the entity class makes that more convenient.